# Open popup from hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, hyperlink, dom-events

I have this code in Google Map infobox which shows hyperlink once the user will open the infobox for the Google marker.

I want once the user will click on that link the page to be open in popup window not in a new tab or new page.
This is the code I have:

```
infoWindow.setContent('<div style="width:200px;height:80px;"><IMG BORDER="0" width="100" height="50" style="margin-right:5px;" ALIGN="Left" SRC='+ decodeURIComponent(data.logofilename)+'>'+data.companyname+'<br /> ' + '<a href="/employer/application.aspx?PostingID='+data.postingid+'&GetPosting=True">' + data.jobtitle+'</a></div>');
```

Any idea how I can solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `target="_blank"` in the href it will stop it from opening in a new tab and open it in the same page. You could also use an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp%E2%80%8E) or ajax to open up the page inside the info-box. If you write ajax it would allow you to run a web page in an `<div></div>`.

Comment: thx for your comment, pls ignore the target="_blank" I forgot to remove that one from the testing I did.